# Fix "CONTENTS" in header using etoc

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, etoc

I use `etoc` package for local TOCs to be inserted after each chaper title via `\localtableofcontents` command. It works fine, but it changes all chapter titles **in headers** into "CONTENTS" title. However section titles are shown correctly. If I skip `\localtableofcontents`, headers become correct.

How to revert headers to default behavior while `\localtableofcontents` is used?

A sample code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoc}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\etocarticlestyle
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter A} 
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1} 
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove those marks completely, your local toc isn't likely to be larger than one page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoc}
\makeatletter
\def\etocarticlestyle{%
    \etocsettocstyle
    {\section *{\contentsname
%                \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname}
%                         {\MakeUppercase \contentsname}
         }
         }
    {}}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\etocarticlestyle
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter A} 
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section 1} 
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps I should modify `etoc` to skip adding those marks for local TOCs. A command such as `\localtableofcontentswithmarks` could then be provided. Or, for back compatibility, the alternative would be to provide `\localtableofcontentswithoutmarks` and not modify the default behavior.

Comment: @jfbu seems like a good idea. I think those marks are a bit distracting.

Comment: all I know is that I didn't pause much to think about the pros and cons of their insertions in `\etocarticlestyle`, and that I may not have had the local TOCs much present in mind at that time.

Comment: @jfbu On a different matter: Great package, thanks :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks... but `etoc` needs a proficiency in `LaTeX` which, for small modifications, is surely a bit overwhelming; as it is possible to use `tocloft` together with `etoc`, I recommand that combination, `tocloft` for easy customizing, and `etoc` for allowing local tables of contents and possibly some of its fancier effects...

Comment: How well  are `etoc` and `tocstyle` working together? `tocloft` isn't working well with KOMA-classes.

Comment: good question: I just don't know, untested. If `etoc` is left in what its doc calls `compatibility mode` the compatibility for line styles should be good as control is really handed over to the class or whatever; but the global appearance (global display style in `etoc`'s doc)  is only emulated, via a copy paste the package author does (and updated only once) of the KOMA-class code for that...

Comment: `\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter A} 
\section{Section 1} 
\chapter{Chapter B} 
\end{document}
` fails when `etoc` is loaded. But looking at the output of `tocstyle` in the log-file i would say: Don't worry ;-)